# Can't find the exe for PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I just installed PyQt for win64 using python 33 from: http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download and can't seem to find its exe in C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4. The linguist, assistant and designer exes are all there. Am I missing something?

I've already reinstalled it 4 times with no change.

Sorry, if this is a stupid question.

Comment: AFAIK, PyQt isn't an executable, it's a library for you to use in your python code, the other executables are helpers to create forms or localize your software.

Comment: You can use `pyqt` like this, `import PyQt4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect from this exe?

I'm not realy into this, but it seems like PyQt is like a module you can include in your python code (like `import QtCore`) and not an actual application to execute.

see [here for the components you can import](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/introduction.html#pyqt4-components) and [here about PyQt not being an actual application](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro). You can then use python to make applications with Qt.